# Magento Cache, what function does it have?

Tags: magento-1.9

What function does the cache have in magento?

Thankfull for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below methods:

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache()
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```